# Store all the updated data from Cloud Firestore in real-time

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a project in which an android app updates a location field inside Cloud Firestore in real-time. Currently it is updating the location which means the previous location data is lost.
I want to maintain a history of all the locations so I need to store the data before it is updated.
Does anyone know how I can store this data?
Also this data will be used for analysis later on so a SQL type structured would be preferred.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is to store the information in a different collection. Then if you want to analyze the information, you can export the data from [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore) to [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs), it is a Google Cloud's fully managed, petabyte-scale and cost-effective analytics data warehouse that lets you run analytics over vast amounts of data in near real time. BigQuery lets you focus on finding meaningful insights using standard SQL.

Comment: BigQuery looks very useful. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: You are welcome, if you consider that my response helped you, could you mark it as accepted?